# Close an entire bootstrap tab-pane

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my problem. I have a tab-content div with several tab-panes with content for each tab. I want to implement a close button at the end of a tab-pane (usually for each tab-pane, so it can be closed, but for now one would do). The close button should hide the content of the pane and should disappear TOGETHER with the pane. It is part of it, after all. Here comes the problem. There are two options to do that and neither seems to work fine. "Toggle" hides the content but the outline of the pane remains visible even if it contains no information. "Hide" does it great, but then it never opens the content when the tab is re-selected.

Is there a similar case somewhere here already? I am trying to prepare a JSFiddle with an example, but for some reasons it doesn't display any content at all... I will post it once it is ready.

I hope you might have an idea how to make it work. There are many example here for buttons which are always visible, but mine should disappear with the pane itself. And it is not a bootstrap modal.

Thanks!

EDIT: This is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m4a3ssfd/6/

```
<nav class="navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container" id="tabs">
            <button type="button" class="pull-left navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="tabList">
                    <li id="lineupTab"><a href="#lineup" data-toggle="tab">LINE-UP</a></li>
                    <li id="statsTab"><a href="#statistics" data-toggle="tab">STATS</a></li>
                    <li id="resultsTab"><a href="#results" data-toggle="tab">RESULTS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="lineup">
            no text yet
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane container fade collapse collapse-group" id="statistics">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="databox">
                        <div class="content">
                            <b>some text</b>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="databox">
                        <div class="content">
                            <b>some text</b>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#statistics" id="closeStats">x</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane container fade" id="results">
            no text yet
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

The tab-panes are not shown here for some reason, otherwise they work fine on my machine.

Comment: If you have any screen shot... please attach to help us.

Comment: We are waiting for your fiddle attempt to help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry I couldn't provide you with a better fiddle, but I solved it using jQuery. I found no straight bootstrap answer, so a very short snippet of jQuery did the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#statsTab").on("click", function() {
    $("#statistics").css("display", "block");

    $("#closeStats").on("click", function() {
        $("#statistics").css("display", "none");
        $("#tabList li.active").removeClass("active");
    });
  });
});
```

The idea is basically to take care of the close button inside the tab-pane by hiding the view of the active panel and then deactivating the active link, so that the menu returns to its initial situation of showing no default tabs.